# Symfony find user by role (JSON array Doctrine property)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am doing a small project where I have an entity with a roles property which consists of an array.

What I am trying to do is, in some controller, find an existing entity which has a specific role inside of the roles array.

I am trying to use the `findOneBy()` method, but I can't seem to make it work, it always returns null even though entities with the specific role I'm trying to find exist.

Here is my entity and its properties:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SalarieRepository::class)
 */
class Salarie
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $service;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    // Getters & setters
}
```

And here is an example of something I tried with `findOneBy()` inside a controller, that returns `null`:

```
$rolecheck = $this->salarieRepository->findOneBy(["roles" => ["ROLE_RESPONSABLE_RH"]]);
```

When I try with any other property of the entity which isn't an array it works well, if I do something like this:

```
$rolecheck = $this->salarieRepository->findOneBy(["nom" => "test"]);
dd($rolecheck);
```

It will show the right entity :

```
SalarieController.php on line 47:
App\Entity\Salarie {#1501 ▼
  -id: 6
  -nom: "test"
  -prenom: "test"
  -email: "test@test.test"
  -telephone: null
  -service: "Graphisme"
  -roles: array:3 [▼
    0 => "ROLE_RESPONSABLE_RH"
    1 => "ROLE_RESPONSABLE_SERVICE"
    2 => "ROLE_SALARIE"
  ]
}
```

Where we can also see it does have the roles array with the role I'm trying to find inside it.

Any clues on how I could try to find one entity which has the specific role `"ROLE_RESPONSABLE_RH"`?

Comment: What is your DBMS ?

Comment: @AymDev I am using MariaDB

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `$roles` property is of type `json`, which means it is stored as this in your database:

```json
["ROLE_RESPONSABLE_RH", "ROLE_RESPONSABLE_SERVICE", "ROLE_SALARIE"]
```

You need to ask Doctrine if the JSON array contains the role, but you can't do that with the `findOneBy()` method.

When you hit the ORM limitations you can use a [Native Query with ResultSetMapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/native-sql.html). It allows you to write a pure SQL query using specific features of your DBMS but still get entity objects.

Create this method in your `SalarieRepository` class:

```php
public function findByRole(string $role): array
{
    // The ResultSetMapping maps the SQL result to entities
    $rsm = $this->createResultSetMappingBuilder('s');

    $rawQuery = sprintf(
        'SELECT %s
        FROM salarie s 
        WHERE /* your WHERE clause depending on the DBMS */',
        $rsm->generateSelectClause()
    );

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($rawQuery, $rsm);
    $query->setParameter('role', $role);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Then you need to replace the comment I put in the `WHERE` clause depending on the DBMS:

**MariaDB** - [JSON_SEARCH()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_search/):

```sql
SELECT %s
FROM salarie s 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(s.roles, 'one', :role) IS NOT NULL
```

**MySQL** - [JSON_CONTAINS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

```sql
SELECT %s
FROM salarie s 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(s.roles, :role, '$')
```

**Warning:** you must enclose the `role` parameter with double quotes:

```php
$query->setParameter('role', sprintf('"%s"', $role));
```

**PostgreSQL** - [jsonb escaped "?" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html):

```sql
SELECT %s
FROM salarie s 
WHERE s.roles::jsonb ?? :role
```

**Warning:** will require PHP 7.4+. See the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_escape_placeholders)

Comment: @SolalBPS you're welcome ! By the way I just realized my answer provides a way to get multiple users. If you really need to perform a *"find one by role"* I think you just need to add a `LIMIT` clause and return `$query->getOneOrNullResult()` at the end of the method.

Comment: even though i don't _need_ it, i tried it, added `LIMIT 1` to the query and returned `$query->getOneOrNullResult()`  and it worked well. Thanks to your answers and what i learnt from them, i was also able to implement a `findOneByRoleAndService()` method which helped me and saved me a lot of time and unnecessary code. Again, thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

1. CAST JSON to TEXT

```
class JSONText extends FunctionNode
{
    private $expr1;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf(
            "CAST(%s AS TEXT)",
            $this->expr1->dispatch($sqlWalker)
        );
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->expr1 = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

2. Add to your Doctrine DQL:

```
dql:
    string_functions:
        JSON_TEXT: YOUR_NAMESPACE\JSONText
```

3. Use your cast function

```
$qb->andWhere("JSON_TEXT(d.topics) LIKE '%$role%'")
```